# Import en.json from i18n folder into component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I use Angular 4 and I have my exemplary component with .ts file in one folder and en.json file in assets/i18n folder. en.json file consists of objects with key:value translations.

Is there any way to import en.json file into Angular component .ts file so I can use objects that the en.json contains?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n, http://www.ngx-translate.com/

Comment: send `http` request and get it. are you facing any problems doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create a definition file with this, or add this to your `typings.d.ts` :

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

2 - In your component, simply add

```
import * as data from './example.json';
```

Your file is now imported, you can find your translations into the `data.key` variable !